# I want the first three words of a paragraph as a string with spaces between the words

Tags: applescript

Is there a way, say using a space char as the string delimiter, set a string to the first three words of a paragraph including spaces.

For example

```
set a to "This is my test string"
set b to words 1 thru to 3 of a
set c to words 1 thru to 3 of a as rich text
return {b,c}
```

Returns {{"This","is","my"},"Thisismy"}

I want to set a variable so in this case of a, it would be set to "This is my".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's explain what happens. `words 1 thru 3 of a as rich text` is getting a range of words as an list. Then as rich text (which should be as string) coerces the list into an string. When you coerce an list (or record) to an string AppleScript will use an separator called text item delimiter. By default it is set to "". This means there is no separator (delimiter) used and the words are glued together. But let's see what happens when we set temporarily the text item delimiters to space.

```
set a to "This is my test string"
set b to words 1 thru 3 of a
set {oldTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, space}
set c to words 1 thru 3 of a as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID
return {b, c}
```

now it returns `{{"This", "is", "my"}, "This is my"}`

Comment: Thanks dj bw.I had as text and the compiler made it "rich text". Is string a type and "rich text" not a type or something like that?

Comment: rich text is a type but not AppleScript's default string type. string, unicode text and text has merged into one type since AppleScript 2.0 and they mean the same. They should be used when using AppleScript strings. Rich type, in your case, could mean a class from an application or scripting addition because it won't compile on most machines.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining they're all the same type (string, unicode text and text). Are there any other differences b/w them (can't be can there if they really are the one same type with two names)? Does that mean they are all UTF-16? Docs seem to imply string and text are the same but Unicode is different. (Search "encoding" in user guide.)

Comment: Just for the record: Unicode itself is not an encoding, and the types are unicode. When reading or writing to an file, or using a do shell script, the proper encoding is used. The encoding that will be used depends on the command itself (or it's parameters).

Comment: Tip: If you wish to preserve the original white space and any other non-word characters between the words, use `text (word 1) thru (word 3) of a`.

Comment: Ah another subtlety of the at times impenetrable AppleScript grammar! Thanks foo.